# Maven build error

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build (mvn clean install having cleared my local repository) a project but I get the error below. The grammar's appalling and I haven't got a clue what it's getting at, can anyone shed any light on it for me?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ear: Could not resolve dependencies for project
com.htu:ear:ear:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.htu:web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in
http://repository.jboss.com/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not
be reattempted until the update interval of jboss has elapsed or updates are forced ->
[Help 1]
```

Software versions, FWIW:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.1 (r1038046; 2010-11-23 10:58:32+0000)
Java version: 1.6.0_22
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.6.5" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is basically saying that it can't find the artifact: `com.htu:web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

I'm assuming that this is something you or your team controls. Therefore, I'd suggest the following:

- Check to make sure that this artifact is properly deployed - it should be present in your artifact server (eg: Nexus, Archiva)
- Check to make sure it is installed in your local repository (on your disk under .m2)

Chances are, one or both of these are off somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If com.htu is your own package, you will need to run mvn clean install on that dependencies too. Maven doesn't build your depending project for you.